# c# class variable still null after calling function

Tags: c#, class, variables

After calling func1 variable mydata stays null. In debug mode I see that in func3 it sets data to string. why it doesn't pass value after exiting function?

Class example

```
class myclass
{
    public string mydata;

    public int func1()
    {

        //....
            func2(/**/, mydata);
        //....
        return 1;
    }


    private int func2(/**/,data)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[1000];
            //...
                func3(arr,data);
            //...
        return 1;
    }


    private void func3(byte[] arr, string data)
    {
        char[] a = new char[100];
        //...

        data = new string(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you're passing by value, not by reference?

Comment: Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, parameters are passed by value; it means that what is passed is actually a copy of the variable (which is a copy of the reference in the case of a reference type like `string`). When `func3` assigns `data`, it only modifies a local copy of the variable.

Now, if you change `func2` and `func3` signatures so that `data` is passed by reference, you will get the expected result:

```
public int func1()
{

    //....
        func2(/**/, ref mydata);
    //....
    return 1;
}


private int func2(/**/,ref string data)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[1000];
        //...
            func3(arr, ref data);
        //...
    return 1;
}


private void func3(byte[] arr, ref string data)
{
    char[] a = new char[100];
    //...

    data = new string(a);
}
```

I suggest you read Jon Skeet's [article about parameter passing](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It because all arguments are passed by reference into the method. `data = new string(a);`
 crates new instance of a string with new reference.

```
var o = new object(); // reference 1

function void method(object something)
{
   // here we have reference to something in stack, so if we will assign new value to it, we will work with stack copy of a reference.
   something = null; // we removed reference to something in method not initial o instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's an **instance** variable, not a **class** variable. To be a class variable it would have to be declared `static`.

Second, why do you hand it down as an argument to the respective functions? The way you're doing it, it creates a separate string in every method and doesn't refer to the original one. Just go ahead and call it directly:

```
private void func3(byte[] arr)
{
    //...
    mydata = new string(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the reference to the string `mydata` by value. This means `mydata` will still refer to the same object after the function returns, regardless of what you do inside the function. If you wanted to change the string `mydata`, you could pass the reference by reference:

```
public int func1()
{
    //....
        func2(/**/, ref mydata);
    //....
    return 1;
}

private int func2(/**/, ref string data)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[1000];
        //...
            func3(arr, ref data);
        //...
    return 1;
}

private void func3(byte[] arr, ref string data)
{
    char[] a = new char[100];
    //...

    data = new string(a);
}
```